# Get-ADuser multiple exclude users

Tags: powershell

I want to exclude some users inside AD.

e.g

```
TST292736ca
PRD1212ca
PRD212132121ca
PRD293873
PRD122
TST141444
TST122
cyberhw12
```

and so on

My question is : I want to exclude  "Users starting with TST and ending with ca" , "Users starting with PRD and ending with ca" , "starting with cyber" users.

script :

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress |where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} | where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like that: fill `$ADUsersExcluded` with excluded users and with `foreach` and `if` fill new array with users `$filteredUsers`.

```
[array]$ADUsersExcluded = $null
$ADUsersExcluded += Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "TST*ca"}
$ADUsersExcluded += Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "PRD*ca"}
$ADUsersExcluded += Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "cyber*"}

$AllUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name,PasswordNeverExpires,PasswordExpired,PasswordLastSet,EmailAddress | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} | Where-Object { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | Where-Object { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }
[array]$filtered = $null
foreach($user in $AllUsers) {
    if($ADUsersExcluded -notcontains $user){
        $filteredUsers += $user
    }
}
$filteredUsers
```

Comment: `[array]$filtered = $null` should probably be `[array]$filteredUser = @()` (incorrect name and not `$Null`). Besides, [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it might get very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

First, dont forget to import AD module. Check condition values.

```
[array] $ADExcludedUser = 'User1', 'User2', 'User3'

$AllUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress | Where-Object { ( $_.Enabled -eq "True" ) -and ( $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false ) -and ( $_.name -notin $ADExcludedUser ) }
$AllUsersExceptExcluded = $AllUsers | where-object { $_.name -notin $ADExcludedUser }

write-host -object $AllUsersExceptExcluded
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex `-notmatch` for this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq $true" -Properties PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress |
Where-Object { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false -and $_.PasswordExpired -eq $false -and  $_.Name -notmatch '^(TST|PRD).*ca$|^cyber' }
```

If you need case-sensitivity, change `notmatch` into `-cnotmatch`